# boost log library missing in CentOS 7 Base Repo

Tags: boost, mariadb, centos7, boost-log, software-collections

I'm learning to use boost log and i'm using centOs7 environment.

I installed boost-devel package on CentOS7 and `yum` downloaded it from CentOS7 Base Repo. After installation i inspected and found boost log headers and .so are missing.  When exploring on the internet found CentOS Special interest group’s Software Collections Repo and found boost log in mariadb rpm:
`1. rh-mariadb102-boost-log.x86_64`
`2. rh-mariadb101-boost-log.x86_64`

Both of the above are giving boost log so and it’s dependancies from Boost 1.58 source.  But the base boost-devel package is based on Boost 1.53 source.

Due to the version mismatch it might lead to lot of errors in the existing project and i cannot do that.

Any Ideas/suggestions please.

Or is it safe to use boost libs completely from mariadb rpm?

Answer (score 1):

After lot of analysis i found a solution:

CentOs7 base/updates repo does not contain latest boost library rpms (don't know the reason).  They are stuck at boost 1.53 version and boost log has been part of boost frame work from 1.54 version.  Other packages like mariadb and mongodb might have had similar issue like my self and they had made their own rpms of boost libraries and made them as part of their package.

To solve my problem of getting latest version of boost libraries, we have to either add fedora base repo to our centos repos and get latest boost libs or add epel repo to cent os repost and get the latest boost libs.

When i to get latest boost rpms by adding fedora base repo, it had failed with error saying other dependancies with perl version on the os are conflicting and are old.  So, the only option left is to get it from epel repo and it worked fine. below are the steps followed to add epel repo and get latest boost libs:

1. sudo yum install epel-release
2. yum search boost169-devel.x86_64
3. yum install boost169-devel.x86_64

At second step verify the information.

References:
epel repo installation on centos: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-redhat-7-x/